# AS3 Sliding Puzzle with Tweens

Tags: actionscript-3

I was wondering how can a sliding puzzle can be achieved like here:

> http://mypuzzle.org/sliding

i have googled all the way but unable to find any tutorial

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Have you tried anything and are stuck somewhere or are you actually asking how to approach the entire project? If the latter, your question won't be received very well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) for tweening objects.

And I found a lot of tutorials while googling.
For example http://ajaybadgujar.com/2011/12/06/as3-number-slide-puzzle-game-for-beginners/

Or [here](http://www.puzzlescripts.com/nm-Sliding_Puzzle_AS3_Simple-cp-39) you can find a lot of topics and source code related to puzzles

If you think you start making the application straight away, you are kinda wrong.
You have to break the app down and think what you really need.
Some quick simple model as an example:

- Main menu
- Grid (as array)
- Tiles

  - Filled in grid array and updated via loops
  - Contain their own picture
  - Attach event listeners to objects (MouseEvent.CLICK or others)
- Check for a win situation with every move.